# Error while saving an image

Tags: c#

I want to save an image after some changes in image. 
but I am getting an error while calling .Save() function.

```
            var tempapth = Server.MapPath("..//Images//Temp//" + btnfile.FileName);
            btnfile.SaveAs(tempapth);
            using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(tempapth))
            {
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                fileStream.CopyTo(ms);
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                System.Drawing.Image img1 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
                fileStream.Close();
                var bmp1 = img1.GetThumbnailImage(100, 150, null, IntPtr.Zero);
                bmp1.Save(path);
            }
```

bmp1.save(path);

give an error

A generic error occurred in GDI+

Comment: You know, the usual stuff: What error? Where? Stacktrace?

Comment: A generic error occurred in GDI+

Comment: What's the content of the `path` variable you're passing to `bmp1.Save(path)`?

Comment: path is my folder location where i want to save my image

Comment: I know what the `path` variable is *supposed* to contain. Still we like to see the full code. Add a file name to the path and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**
The OP changed the question after I wrote this reply. Previously, there was also a `path` variable declared, which contained  a path name (but no file name).

In the first version of your code, you had a path name without a file name (`Server.MapPath("..//Images//Category//" + catid + "//");`). To save, you need to add a file name, too, like:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("..//Images//Category//" + catid + "//Image.bmp");
```

Comment: temppath is different i am using temppath to store for a while after correction i am using actual path.

Comment: Still, there's no file name in `path`.

Comment: I have an image, i saved this to a temp folder.

Comment: and then I read from that temp folder and correct the dimension of image and want to save

Comment: Yes. Now you load it an try to save it to another file. An error occurs while doing that, so you need to tell us what's in the `path` variable.

Comment: Add a *file name* and try again. Like `D:\abc\Images\Category\2\Image.bmp`.

Answer (score 0):

The `path` variable contains the name of a folder, not a file.

Use something like:

```
bmp1.Save(Path.Combine(path, btnfile.FileName));
```

Side note, the character `/` doesn't have a special meaning in a string, it should not be escaped. Use:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("../Images/Category/" + catid + "/");
```

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
var srcPath = Server.MapPath("..//Images//Temp//" + btnfile.FileName);
if (!File.Exists(srcPath)
{
    throw new Exception(string.Format("Could not find source file at {0}", srcPath));
}

var srcImage = Image.FromFile(srcPath);
var thumb = srcImage.GetThumbnailImage(100, 150, null, IntPtr.Zero);

var destPath = Server.MapPath("..//Images//Category//" + catid + "//");
if (!Directory.Exists(destPath))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(destPath);
}

thumb.Save(Path.Combine(destPath, btnfile.FileName));
```